# Update Table in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

In MS-Access 2007, I have a table, `[Test_Master]` where I have a field `[DT_REPORT]`. I want to update `[Test_Norm_Due] by 2 months` if field `[Size] = "small"`. If the field `"Size" = "Med."` then by 3 months. I create below query but it is throwing `Syntax error`. Can someone help.

```
UPDATE Test_Master 
SET Test_Master.Test_Norm_Due = 
    IIF((([Test_Master]![Size]="small")), DateAdd(("m",2,[Test_Master]![DT_REPORT]))), 
         IIF((([Test_Master]![Size]="med.")), DateAdd(("m",3,[Test_Master]![DT_REPORT])));
```

Comment: Do you need it to be in one single UPDATE statement? I would just break it in three statements, it would be much easier to read and understand it later. I would do something like: 
`UPDATE RBIA_Master SET RBIA_Master.RBI_Norm_Due = DateAdd ("m",2,[RBIA_Master]![DT_REPORT])
WHERE RBIA_Master.Size="small";`

Comment: Thanks Pravin. I am using the method suggested as work around. It is working fine. I have sequenced multiple queries in a Macro. But still I would prefer to have a single update query.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe you have a problem with your parentheses - try nesting them using an external Text editor (like notepad++) for greater visibility - also, you are using extra parentheses that are getting in your way, try simplifying; and you're missing one final condition - what should happen with Test_Norm_Due when Size is neither "small" nor "med."

Note that syntax for IIF is:

```
IIF (condition, value if true, value if false).
```

You are nesting IIFs, so you should have something like:

```
IIF (condition, value if true, IIF(other condition, value if true, value if false))
```

Try something like this (I broke it in multiple lines just to try to make it more visible for you).

```
UPDATE Test_Master SET Test_Master.Test_Norm_Due = 
IIF (([Test_Master]![Size]="small"), 
       DateAdd("m",2,[Test_Master]![DT_REPORT]), 
        IIF (([Test_Master]![Size]="med."), 
               DateAdd("m",3,[Test_Master]![DT_REPORT]), 
               {missing value - What happens if it's neither "small" nor "med."} ));
```